# Orchard Custom Settings Not Persisting

Tags: orchardcms

I'm pulling my hair out on this one; it should be so simple yet I can't figure out the issue.

I'm trying to simply save some custom settings in my module. I used the Orchard.Email module as an example on how to plug into the 'Settings' menu; my code is as follows:

**Migrations.cs**

```cs
public class CustomSettingsMigrations : DataMigrationImpl {
    public int Create() {
        SchemaBuilder.CreateTable("CustomSettingsPartRecord", table => table
            .ContentPartRecord()
            .Column<string>("GatewayUrl")
            .Column<string>("MerchantId")
            .Column<string>("MerchantPassword")
            .Column<bool>("SandboxMode")
            .Column<string>("SandboxGatewayUrl")
            .Column<string>("SandboxMerchantId")
            .Column<string>("SandboxMerchantPassword")
            );

            return 1;
    }
}
```

**Models/CustomSettingsPartRecord.cs**

```cs
public class CustomSettingsPartRecord : ContentPartRecord {
    public virtual string GatewayUrl { get; set; }
    public virtual string MerchantId { get; set; }
    public virtual string MerchantPassword { get; set; }
    public virtual bool SandboxMode { get; set; }
    public virtual string SandboxGatewayUrl { get; set; }
    public virtual string SandboxMerchantId { get; set; }
    public virtual string SandboxMerchantPassword { get; set; }

    public CustomSettingsPartRecord() {
        SandboxMode = true;
    }
}
```

**Models/CustomSettingsPart.cs**

```cs
public class CustomSettingsPart : ContentPart<CustomSettingsPartRecord> {
    private readonly ComputedField<string> _password = new ComputedField<string>();

    public ComputedField<string> PasswordField {
        get { return _password; }
    }

    public string GatewayUrl {
        get { return Record.GatewayUrl; }
        set { Record.GatewayUrl = value; }
    }

    public string MerchantId {
        get { return Record.MerchantId; }
        set { Record.MerchantId = value; }
    }

    public string MerchantPassword {
        get { return Record.MerchantPassword; }
        set { Record.MerchantPassword = value; }
    }

    public bool SandboxMode {
        get { return Record.SandboxMode; }
        set { Record.SandboxMode = value; }
    }

    public string SandboxGatewayUrl {
        get { return Record.SandboxGatewayUrl; }
        set { Record.SandboxGatewayUrl = value; }
    }

    public string SandboxMerchantId {
        get { return Record.SandboxMerchantId; }
        set { Record.SandboxMerchantId = value; }
    }

    public string SandboxMerchantPassword {
        get { return Record.SandboxMerchantPassword; }
        set { Record.SandboxMerchantPassword = value; }
    }

    public bool IsValid() {
        return ((!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Record.GatewayUrl)
                 && !String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Record.MerchantId)) ||
                (Record.SandboxMode && !String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Record.SandboxGatewayUrl) &&
                 !String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Record.SandboxMerchantId)));
    }
}
```

**Handlers/CustomSettingsPartHandler.cs**

```cs
[UsedImplicitly]
public class CustomSettingsPartHandler : ContentHandler {
    private readonly IEncryptionService _encryptionService;

    public CustomSettingsPartHandler(IRepository<CustomSettingsPartRecord> repository, IEncryptionService encryptionService) {
        T = NullLocalizer.Instance;
        Logger = NullLogger.Instance;

        _encryptionService = encryptionService;
        Filters.Add(new ActivatingFilter<CustomSettingsPart>("Site"));
        Filters.Add(StorageFilter.For(repository));

        OnLoaded<CustomSettingsPart>(LazyLoadHandlers);
    }

    public Localizer T { get; set; }
    public new ILogger Logger { get; set; }

    void LazyLoadHandlers(LoadContentContext context, CustomSettingsPart part) {
        part.PasswordField.Getter(() => {
            try {
                return String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(part.Record.MerchantPassword) ? String.Empty : Encoding.UTF8.GetString(_encryptionService.Decode(Convert.FromBase64String(part.Record.MerchantPassword)));
            }
            catch (Exception) {
                Logger.Error("The merchant password could not be decrypted. It might be corrupt, try to reset it.");
                return null;
            }
        });

        part.PasswordField.Setter(value => part.Record.MerchantPassword = String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(value) ? String.Empty : Convert.ToBase64String(_encryptionService.Encode(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(value))));
    }

    protected override void GetItemMetadata(GetContentItemMetadataContext context) {
        if (context.ContentItem.ContentType != "Site")
            return;
        base.GetItemMetadata(context);
        context.Metadata.EditorGroupInfo.Add(new GroupInfo(T("Custom")));
    }
}
```

**Drivers/CustomSettingsPartDriver.cs**

```cs
public class CustomSettingsPartDriver : ContentPartDriver<CustomSettingsPart> {
    private const string TemplateName = "Parts/CustomSettings";

    public CustomSettingsPartDriver() {
        T = NullLocalizer.Instance;
    }

    public Localizer T { get; set; }

    protected override string Prefix { get { return "CustomSettings"; } }

    protected override DriverResult Editor(CustomSettingsPart part, dynamic shapeHelper) {
        return ContentShape("Parts_CustomSettings_Edit",
            () => shapeHelper.EditorTemplate(TemplateName: TemplateName, Model: part, Prefix: Prefix))
            .OnGroup("custom");
    }

    protected override DriverResult Editor(CustomSettingsPart part, IUpdateModel updater, dynamic shapeHelper) {
        return ContentShape("Parts_CustomSettings_Edit", () => {
            var previousPassword = part.MerchantPassword;
            updater.TryUpdateModel(part, Prefix, null, null);

            // restore password if the input is empty, meaning it has not been changed
            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(part.MerchantPassword)) {
                part.MerchantPassword = previousPassword;
            }
            return shapeHelper.EditorTemplate(TemplateName: TemplateName, Model: part, Prefix: Prefix)
            .OnGroup("custom");
        });
    }
}
```

**Views/EditorTemplates/Parts/CustomSettings.cshtml**

```cs
@model CustomModule.Models.CustomSettingsPart
@{
    Script.Require("jQuery");            
}
<fieldset>
    <legend>@T("Custom Settings")</legend>
    <div>
        <label for="@Html.FieldIdFor(m => m.GatewayUrl)">@T("Gateway Url")</label>
        @Html.EditorFor(m => m.GatewayUrl)
        @Html.ValidationMessage("GatewayUrl", "*")
    </div>
    <div>
        <label for="@Html.FieldIdFor(m => m.MerchantId)">@T("Merchant ID")</label>
        @Html.EditorFor(m => m.MerchantId)
        @Html.ValidationMessage("MerchantId", "*") 
    </div>
    <div>
        <label for="@Html.FieldIdFor(m => m.MerchantPassword)">@T("Merchant Password")</label>
        @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.MerchantPassword)
        @Html.ValidationMessage("MerchantPassword", "*")
    </div>
    <div>
        @Html.EditorFor(m => m.SandboxMode)
        <label for="@Html.FieldIdFor(m => m.SandboxMode)" class="forcheckbox">@T("Enable Sandbox Mode (for testing)")</label>
        @Html.ValidationMessage("SandboxMode", "*")
    </div>
    <div id="sandboxSettings">
        <div>
            <label for="@Html.FieldIdFor(m => m.SandboxGatewayUrl)">@T("Sandbox Gateway Url")</label>
            @Html.EditorFor(m => m.SandboxGatewayUrl)
            @Html.ValidationMessage("SandboxGatewayUrl", "*")
        </div>
        <div>
            <label for="@Html.FieldIdFor(m => m.SandboxMerchantId)">@T("Sandbox Merchant ID")</label>
            @Html.EditorFor(m => m.SandboxMerchantId)
            @Html.ValidationMessage("SandboxMerchantId", "*") 
        </div>
        <div>
            <label for="@Html.FieldIdFor(m => m.SandboxMerchantPassword)">@T("Sandbox Merchant Password")</label>
            @Html.EditorFor(m => m.SandboxMerchantPassword)
            @Html.ValidationMessage("SandboxMerchantPassword", "*")
        </div>
    </div>
</fieldset>
@using (Script.Foot()) {
    <script>
        $('#@Html.FieldIdFor(m => m.SandboxMode)').on('click', function() {
            $('#sandboxSettings').toggle($(this).prop('checked'));
        });
    </script>
}
```

I have the **Placement.info** and I can access the View through the "Custom" menu item underneath "Settings" in the main menu. The View loads fine, and when I enter some details and click 'Save', the form is sent find and will hit the **CustomSettingsPartDriver.cs** `DriverResult Editor(CustomSettingsPart part, IUpdateModel updater..` method.

I *believe* this is where the issue could be, as it doesn't hit any breakpoints inside the `return ContentShape("Parts_CustomSettings_Edit, () => {` lambda expression.

Could anyone shed any light on how I can resolve this? I'm sure it's a simple issue, but I've been trying to figure this one out for a while unsuccessfully. Thanks!

Comment: Have you done a trace via Profiler? Maybe a SQL error isn't getting reported back

Comment: Hi Nick; I ran a trace and compared the results to the Email module settings. I was able to determine that an UPDATE call is never made, which makes sense as the form values never persist. No errors are being reported, so I'm assuming that UPDATE is never called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I managed to figure this one out. I feel silly asking questions then answering them myself, but if it saves one person time in the future, then it's worth it.

The issue was, as I expected, in the Driver. I appended the `.OnGroup()` extension to the wrong Shape.

Below is the fixed Driver code:

```c#
protected override DriverResult Editor(CustomSettingsPart part, IUpdateModel updater, dynamic shapeHelper) {
    return ContentShape("Parts_CustomSettings_Edit", () => {
        var previousPassword = part.MerchantPassword;
        updater.TryUpdateModel(part, Prefix, null, null);

        // restore password if the input is empty, meaning it has not been changed
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(part.MerchantPassword)) {
            part.MerchantPassword = previousPassword;
        }
        return shapeHelper.EditorTemplate(TemplateName: TemplateName, Model: part, Prefix: Prefix);
        // Offending extension -> .OnGroup("custom");

    }).OnGroup("custom"); // In the correct location
}
```

**facepalm**

Comment: Yay! Never used the OnGroup method before sorry!